# Accessing property with space in template expression

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the below code structure:

```
"name": {

        "age": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "how  old": "23"


                }
            },
```

my JSON key having space. How to access the property in an Angular template? I was doing the below but it's giving an error.

```html
<span>{{age.data.'how  old'}}</span>
```

Comment: Just like everywhere else in the JS ecosystem, when the key isn't a valid identifier, you have to use the `[]` notation instead. `age.data.'how  old'` is not syntactically valid.

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman some parsing error and jonrsharpe can you provide me exact line how i can do it.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman just a type error.wont effect

Comment: Use {{age.data['how old']}} to access the property

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman JS allows a comma after the last element of an array or object.

Comment: It`s just Awesome......WOW @Imran..It worked..Thanks A lot Bro..

Comment: @Barmar, Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{age.data['how  old']}}
```

or, probably

```
{{name.age[0].data['how  old']}}
```

Comment: @NaveenSuryawanshi, if it's working, you should consider accepting the answer.